# PostgreSQL remote connection outside local network

Tags: postgresql, postgis, psql, ssh-tunnel, pgadmin-4

I manage a postgresql DB on a windows server, the local connection with a client workstation on the postgresql server works perfectly, but when leaving the local network, the connection fails. I have tried several configurations offered on similar topics, but without success.

Here are some solutions already tried:

- listen_addresses = '*'
- port = 5432
- host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5 ... host all all 0.0.0.0/0 trust ... client side and server side postgresql
- I disabled Windows Firewall and created specific inbound / outbound traffic rules for port 5432 ... client side and server windows side
- I tried to create an ssh tunnel via psql, python or the pgAgmin interface but I got stuck on this message: "Failed to create the SSH tunnel. Error: Could not establish session to SSH gateway"

I am convinced that I am wrong on a configuration, but which one? This is the subject of my request ...

Does anyone know how to help me?

thank you,

Comment: can the client workstation at least ping the server? i.e. is the basic network setup of both hosts correct?

Comment: What error does the connection fail with?  It is probably a firewall.  You said you disabled the firewall on both machines, that just leaves all devices between the two.

Comment: @Tom, Yes the basic configuration (local connection) between the postgresql server and the client workstation work correctly

Comment: @jjanes, When I am connected with the local wifi the connection works between the two machines, but with a private connection (at home) I do not have access to the database ... Of course the firewall is disabled on both machines (domain, private and public networks)

Comment: @Naslar, were you able to resolve this issue? If you did, please share - I'm having the same issues and have been researching for 2 days without any luck.